# Jquery FullCalendar, display Week Numbers and Days Names in output

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a Jquery FullCalendar. I was able to get the total values of rows and columns for the values from json. I want to add the Week numbers to the row output and Day names to the column output

> For eg:- This is my row output values 950 500 550 200 and these are my column output values 700 300 300 200 250 200 250

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/6jhkLh9x/13/) For the work until now!!

I am looking to generate the output as follows:-

> For Row Values **(W 44)950, (W 45)500, (W 46)550, (W 47)200  Total:(2200)** and for column values something like this **(Sun)700 (Mon)300 (Tue)300 (Wed)200 (Thu)250 (Fri)200 (Sat)250**

Complete code:-

```
var baseEvent;

var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 weekNumbers: true,
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
eventRender: eventRenderCallback,
viewRender: viewRenderCallback,
eventAfterAllRender: eventAfterAllRenderCallback,
defaultView: 'month',
events: [
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 2 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 4 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 6 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 7 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 8 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 9 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 10 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 11 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 12 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 13 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 14 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 15 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 16 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 17 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Nov 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 2 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 4 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 5 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 6 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 7 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 8 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 9 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 10 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 11 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 12 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 13 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 14 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 15 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 16 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 17 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 18 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 19 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 20 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 21 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 22 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 23 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 24 2015"},

    {"title":"500","start":"Dec 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Dec 2 2015"}

]
});

var rowTotals = [];
var columnTotals = [];
var offset = 0;

function eventRenderCallback(event,element){
var viewDateMonth = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getMonth();
if(event.start.getMonth() == viewDateMonth){
    addToDateArray(event.start.getDate(), parseInt(event.title));
}
}

function eventAfterAllRenderCallback(view){
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    total += rowTotals[i];
    var label = $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
    label.html(rowTotals[i]);     
}

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    var label = $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
    label.html(columnTotals[i]);     
}

$("#total").html("("+total+")");
}

function viewRenderCallback(view,element){
offset = $("tr.fc-week.fc-first td.fc-other-month").length;
rowTotals = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
columnTotals = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

if(view.name == "agendaDay"){
    $("#rows label").show();
    $("#cols label").hide();
    $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (view.start.getDay()+1) + ")").show();
}else if(view.name == "agendaWeek"){
    $("#cols label").show();
    $("#rows label").hide();
    var row = Math.floor((view.start.getDate() + offset - 1) / 7);
    $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (row+1) + ")").show();
}else {
    $("#cols label").show();
    $("#rows label").show();
}
}                   

function addToDateArray(date,num){
var pos = date + offset;
var row = Math.floor((pos - 1) / 7);
var col = (pos - 1) % 7

rowTotals[row] += num;
columnTotals[col] += num;
}
```

Please edit the fiddle for any solutions. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the weekNumbers option in fullcalendar, it calculates the week numbers for you. Score! They cab be retrieved from the dom using $(".fc-week-number div"). You can get the day with a simple indexed array of day names.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jhkLh9x/)

```
function eventAfterAllRenderCallback(view){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        total += rowTotals[i];
        var label = $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
        var week = $(".fc-week-number div").eq(i).html();
        label.html("(W"+(week)+") " + rowTotals[i]);     
    }

    var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        var label = $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
        label.html("(" + dayNames[i] + ") " + columnTotals[i]);     
    }

    $("#total").html("("+total+")");
}
```